# C: read json array using fscanf

Tags: c, json

I have an JSON array of arbitrary length in a file like this:

`[ 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18 ]`

I want to get the integers and store them in an new array.

I tried using `fscanf(f, " [ %d , ", data);` to capture the first integer but the fscanf returned -1 (using gcc on Ubuntu terminal).

Is the format specifier wrong? How to skip the square brackets and use comma to separate different integers?

My code here:

```
typedef struct {
    int *data;
    unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;    

intarr_t *intarr_load_json(const char *filename) {

    if (filename == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("file open failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    int char_input = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int num_count = 0;

    //count the # of numbers in the file by counting # of ","
    while ((char_input = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (char_input == 44) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    num_count = count+1;

    printf("num_count is %d\n", num_count);

    intarr_t *intarr_loaded_json = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));

    if (intarr_loaded_json == 0) {
        return NULL; // intarr_loaded_json malloc failed
    }

    if (num_count == 0) {
        intarr_loaded_json->len = num_count;
        intarr_loaded_json->data = NULL;
        return intarr_loaded_json;
    }

    intarr_loaded_json->len = num_count;
    intarr_loaded_json->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_count);

    if (intarr_loaded_json->data == 0) {
        printf("Malloc failed\n");
        return NULL; 
    }

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int i = 0;
    //char temp;
    int value = 0;

    //printf("a is %d\n", a);

    if ((a = fscanf(f, "[ %d , ", intarr_loaded_json->data + i) > 0) {
        printf("got first number\n");
        i++;
    }

    //printf("temp is %c\n", temp);
    printf("a is %d\n", a);

    while ((b = fscanf(f, " , %d", intarr_loaded_json->data + i)) == 1) {
        i++;
        printf("do while loop %d th time\n", i);
    }

    printf("b is %d\n", b);
    // printf("intarr_loaded_json->len is %d\n", intarr_loaded_json->len);

    return intarr_loaded_json;

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently, read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you've provided is too fragmentary for much analysis to be possible.  We need more information to help you — help us to help you by providing it.

Comment: In general, trailing white space on a `scanf()`-family format specification is a bad idea.  However, it is not formally incorrect, and should work.  What is surprising is the use of `*data` — you've not shown how `data` is defined.  It would be more normal to use `&data`, or just `data`.  To use `*data` implies that the code was passed a pointer to a pointer, allocated space for the data, and now initializes that in the shown call to `fscanf()`.  But something went wrong and `-1` was reported — that means EOF or a hard error was detected (is `f` initialized correctly?).

Comment: Use some JSON library. Like [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) or many others

Comment: data is the pointer to an array previously malloc'd (apologize for the careless mistake). f is a stream initialized by fopen correctly.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code.  The problem was unsolvable with the original two lines of code; with the full code, it is not too hard to spot the problem.  That's why the MCVE is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read through the file as far as EOF in order to count the number of commas.  You never rewind the file, so you're at the end of file when you start trying to read the `[`, and `fscanf()` correctly returns `EOF` (aka `-1` — technically, EOF can be any negative number, but in practice it is always `-1`).

Add `rewind(f);` before trying to read the data a second time.

Or, better, don't do the counting up front — allocate more space as needed, usually doubling the size of the allocated array each time you need more space to avoid quadratic copying behaviour.

There could be other problems — more serious than the use of `if (char_input == 44)` instead of `if (char_input == ',')` or the misplaced and non-reachable `fclose(f);`.  But the primary one is you've read to EOF and you don't rewind before trying to reread the data.

Comment: It worked. I used realloc() instead of counting # of integers. Thank you for pointing to my errors and providing strategy